# Best practices to create and serve vector tiles using Tegola

Tags: vector-tiles, tegola

I'm using [**Tegola**](https://tegola.io/) tile server to generate vector tiles from geospatial data that I have in a Postgres/PostGIS database.

Tegola supports fetching data from a PostGIS database directly from a table, and can also manage tile requests by leveraging ST_AsMVT to handle the MVT encoding at the database, using ST_AsMVTGeom(). (They call it "postgis provider" vs "mvt_postgis provider")

If I want to pre-generated tiles, i.e. cache, to use in a client's web app, would it be faster if I use the mvt_postgis provider?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, using a Focused question/Best answer model. Questions which seek opinions are *off-topic* here (no right answer is possible). [Chat] exists for discussion, but it has a minimum reputation requirement, and doesn't see the volume of traffic in our main Q&A site. Please [Edit] your Question to ask a single answerable question.